# Next,js 13: How to adapt useEffect call on root layout?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js13

I want to execute an useEffect call on all pages of my site. Before the Next v13 I called this effect on the `_app.ts`. On Next v13 the root layout replaces the `_app.ts`, but it must be server component (therefore we can't use the useEffect hook inside it).

So how can I execute an useEffect on all pages of my site (without execute it separately on each page)?

I thought about create a context and execute the useEffect inside it. But this isn't the best way, since the context api was not created for this purpose. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could move your `useEffect` to a client component that is rendered inside of `src/app/layout.tsx`. This way it will run no matter which page is rendered by the client.

For example, you could update the `RootLayout` to render it as:

```js
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ClientApplication>
          {children}
        </ClientApplication>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Where `ClientApplication` has the `useEffect` that you want to trigger on the client for every page:

```js
"use client";

export default function ClientApplication({ children }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Client-side effect triggered");
  });

  return children;
}
```